# Accessing string from a structure, by using a series of pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

```
typedef struct {
    char numeVolum[50]; ////this is what interests us!!!
    short int anPublicare; 
    unsigned char stare; 
    int idPersoana; 
} TVolum; 

typedef struct { 
    char numeAutor[50];  
    char codTara[2];  
    int nrVolume; 
    TVolum* volume;  /////this is what interests us!!!
} TAutor;
```

Both of these structures are allocated dynamically! 
listaAutori[0] is an array of pointers to TAutor structures! 
(you can conclude that listaAutori is a TAutor** type)

```
fgets(listaAutori[0] -> numeAutor, 50, input); 
fgets(listaAutori[0] -> codTara, 3, input); 
fgets(listaAutori[0] -> volume[0].numeVolum, 53, input);
```

The first two fgets are reading fine. 
But the third one gives me no output.

```
printf("\nNUme primul volum al lui Agatha: %s\n", listaAutori[0] -> volume[0].numeVolum);
```

In other words, I have two structures, A and B. 
Inside B, I have a string. (pointer to char)

There is a pointer pB in structure A. 
And there is an array of pointers to A.

Like this:

Array of pointers containing pA element -> structure A -> pB -> structure B -> my string.

I am trying to read a line from a file, and store that string inside the numeVolum[50] string. The only way I can access TVolum is by using a pointer to TAutor.

I don't know what is not working, that printf gives me no output. 
It should have printed something. 
(my file from which data is read contains info on every line)

```
Autor* alocaAutor(int nrVolume) 
{ 
    TAutor* autor = (TAutor*)calloc(1, sizeof(TAutor));  
    autor -> volume = (TVolum*)calloc(nrVolume, sizeof(TVolum)); 
    autor -> nrVolume = nrVolume; 
    return autor; 
} 

TAutor** alocaAutori(int nrAutori, int* nrVolumeAutor) 
{
    int i;
    TAutor** vectorAutori = (TAutor**)calloc(nrAutori, sizeof(TAutor*));  
    for(i = 0; i < nrAutori; i++) {
        vectorAutori[i] = alocaAutor(nrVolumeAutor[i]); 
    } 
    return vectorAutori; 
}
```

example of the input file :

```
2 
1 
1
Agatha Christie
UK
Ultimul caz al lui Hercule Poirot
```

I am 100 percent positive that it reads everything before the last line. 
Then when I try to read the last line inside the string from TVolume, it simply doesn't work.

Comment: Where and how did you initialize volume pointer? Also trying to read a max of 53 characters into a string [50] is a potential for overflow

Comment: After I initialize the TAutor*  I also initialize its volume pointer.

Comment: That 53 is random, the string I am reading is less than 25 anyway.

Comment: I am not sure if this particular line is correct: fgets(listaAutori[0] -> volume[0].numeVolum, 53, input); It seems to be pretty long and I have never done that before

Comment: You should add that code. Also maybe an example of input file.

Comment: Code and input example added.

Comment: Apparently, if I add this piece of code between the 2nd and third fgets, it will read properly: char* gunoi; 
 fscanf(input,"\n", gunoi); 
 fgets(volume -> numeVolum, 53, input);    Anyone knows why?!

Comment: *That 53 is random* Why do you use random values to force undefined behavior? `fgets(listaAutori[0] -> codTara, 3, input)` is also wrong because `codTara` is only 2 bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)
```

stops when `n-1` characters have been read ([source](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fgets.htm)). Because the value of `n` in the second `fgets` is `3`, it reads only the `UK` in the input file. The newline character after it is not read yet. It is then read by the *third* `fgets`, which, encountering the newline character immediately, does not read further. Thus, the final line in the input file is not read.

Your edited code (in your comment) works because the `fscanf` reads that newline character and stops at it, leaving the `fgets` to read the final line.

Comment: And you should increase the size of the `codTara` array to `3`. In its current state, your code can exhibit undefined behaviour, because `fgets` appends a null terminator after the characters it reads (given your input file, it would place the terminator at `codTara + 2`, which is in unallocated memory).

Comment: Thank you bro', that's the answer I was looking for. It all makes sense. Deep in my mind I knew it, but I was way too tired last night to assemble the pieces of this puzzle.